# Efficient time series querying in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in my PG db that looks somewhat like this:

```
id | widget_id | for_date | score |
```

Each referenced widget has a lot of these items. It's always 1 per day per widget, but there are gaps.

What I want to get is a result that contains all the widgets for each date since X. The dates are brought in via generate series:

```
 SELECT date.date::date
   FROM generate_series('2012-01-01'::timestamp with time zone,'now'::text::date::timestamp with time zone, '1 day') date(date)
 ORDER BY date.date DESC;
```

If there is no entry for a date for a given widget_id, I want to use the previous one. So say widget 1337 doesn't have an entry on 2012-05-10, but on 2012-05-08, then I want the resultset to show the 2012-05-08 entry on 2012-05-10 as well:

```
Actual data:
widget_id | for_date   | score
1312      | 2012-05-07 | 20
1337      | 2012-05-07 | 12
1337      | 2012-05-08 | 41
1337      | 2012-05-11 | 500

Desired output based on generate series:
widget_id | for_date   | score
1336      | 2012-05-07 | 20
1337      | 2012-05-07 | 12
1336      | 2012-05-08 | 20
1337      | 2012-05-08 | 41
1336      | 2012-05-09 | 20
1337      | 2012-05-09 | 41
1336      | 2012-05-10 | 20
1337      | 2012-05-10 | 41
1336      | 2012-05-11 | 20
1337      | 2012-05-11 | 500
```

Eventually I want to boil this down into a view so I have consistent data sets per day that I can query easily.

**Edit:** Made the sample data and expected resultset clearer

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to list rows for *all* widget_id's at once (like your text at the top implies) or for *a given* `widget_id` (like your example implies)?

Comment: Why is the widget_id=1312 missing in the desired output? And where does the widget_id=1336 come from ?

Comment: Follow-up with solution for missing values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442362/time-series-querying-in-postgres/19452830

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d76d0/2)

```
select
    widget_id,
    for_date,
    case
        when score is not null then score
        else first_value(score) over (partition by widget_id, c order by for_date)
        end score
from (
    select
        a.widget_id,
        a.for_date,
        s.score,
        count(score) over(partition by a.widget_id order by a.for_date) c
    from (
        select widget_id, g.d::date for_date
        from (
            select distinct widget_id
            from score
            ) s
            cross join
            generate_series(
                (select min(for_date) from score),
                (select max(for_date) from score),
                '1 day'
            ) g(d)
        ) a
        left join
        score s on a.widget_id = s.widget_id and a.for_date = s.for_date
) s
order by widget_id, for_date
```

Answer (score 7):

*First* of all, you can have a much simpler `generate_series()` table expression. Equivalent to yours (except for descending order, that contradicts the rest of your question anyways):

```
SELECT generate_series('2012-01-01'::date, now()::date, '1d')::date
```

The type `date` is coerced to `timestamptz` automatically on input. The return type is `timestamptz` either way. I use a subquery below, so I can cast to the output to `date` right away.

*Next*, `max()` as window function returns exactly what you need: the highest value since *frame* start ignoring `NULL` values. Building on that, you get a **radically simple** query.

#### For a given widget_id

Most likely faster than involving `CROSS JOIN` or `WITH RECURSIVE`:

```
SELECT a.day, s.*
FROM  (
   SELECT d.day
         ,max(s.for_date) OVER (ORDER BY d.day) AS effective_date
   FROM  (
      SELECT generate_series('2012-01-01'::date, now()::date, '1d')::date
      ) d(day)
   LEFT   JOIN score s ON s.for_date = d.day
                      AND s.widget_id = 1337 -- "for a given widget_id"
   ) a
LEFT   JOIN score s ON s.for_date = a.effective_date
                   AND s.widget_id = 1337
ORDER  BY a.day;
```

[**->sqlfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/dd2f2/6)

With this query you can put any column from `score` you like into the final `SELECT` list. I put s.* for simplicity. Pick your columns.

If you want to start your output with the first day that actually *has* a score, simply replace the last `LEFT JOIN` with `JOIN`.

#### Generic form for all widget_id's

Here I use a `CROSS JOIN` to produce a row for every widget on every date ..

```
SELECT a.day, a.widget_id, s.score
FROM  (
   SELECT d.day, w.widget_id
         ,max(s.for_date) OVER (PARTITION BY w.widget_id
                                ORDER BY d.day) AS effective_date
   FROM  (SELECT generate_series('2012-05-05'::date
                                ,'2012-05-15'::date, '1d')::date AS day) d
   CROSS  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT widget_id FROM score) AS w
   LEFT   JOIN score s ON s.for_date = d.day AND s.widget_id = w.widget_id
   ) a
JOIN  score s ON s.for_date = a.effective_date
             AND s.widget_id = a.widget_id  -- instead of LEFT JOIN
ORDER BY a.day, a.widget_id;
```

[**->sqlfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c3a22/3)

Comment: Would your cross join less answer work for multiple widget_ids? [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/686f3/1). From the question: _What I want to get is a result that contains all the widgets for each date since X_

Comment: @Clodoaldo: For multiple `widget_id`'s at once, you would have to adapt. I'll have a look at a more generic query. But, also from the question: *for a given widget_id*.

Comment: I like this approach best so far, I was fiddling in a similar direction but failed to put the window functions and joins together. @Clodoaldo is right though, I would like this to also be queryable as a whole, so for example I'd like to ask "what was the average (or max, min, ...) score on date X", which would require something that does not depend on explicit widget ids

Comment: @TheDeadSerious: I added a generic solution to show a row for every `(day, widget)`. Your question could have been more clear on that (your test case, particularly). For aggregates like `max()` or `min()` there is probably a more elegant way! Depends on what you need exactly and is a different question that shall go into a different question.

Comment: And @Clodoaldo is right, of course, that a `CROSS JOIN` is the way to go to produce the raster for the generic solution.

Comment: Sorry, I see that I should have been more specific about this. I thought the suffix "Eventually I want to boil this down into a view so I have consistent data sets per day that I can query easily." would make it clear I'd like a full data set in the results. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Great solution. I've been using a variation on this for a project but have encountered an issue when the "previous" value falls before the time period you are looking at. Check out this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d7a20/1/0) for the simplest example. Is there a way to adjust for this? Thanks!

Comment: @bpaul: Like in my first example, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` ([SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d7a20/3)). If you want something else I suppose you start a *new question* where you provide all details necessary. You can always refer to this one for context.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Thanks for the reply I posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442362/time-series-querying-in-postgres can you take a look?

Answer (score 2):

Using your table structure, I created the following Recursive CTE which starts with your MIN(For_Date) and increments until it reaches the MAX(For_Date).  Not sure if there is a more efficient way, but this appears to work well:

```
WITH RECURSIVE nodes_cte(widgetid, for_date, score) AS (
-- First Widget Using Min Date
 SELECT 
    w.widgetId, 
    w.for_date, 
    w.score
 FROM widgets w 
  INNER JOIN ( 
      SELECT widgetId, Min(for_date) min_for_date
      FROM widgets
      GROUP BY widgetId
   ) minW ON w.widgetId = minW.widgetid 
        AND w.for_date = minW.min_for_date
UNION ALL
 SELECT 
    n.widgetId,
    n.for_date + 1 for_date,
    coalesce(w.score,n.score) score
 FROM nodes_cte n
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT widgetId, Max(for_date) max_for_date
      FROM widgets 
      GROUP BY widgetId
   ) maxW ON n.widgetId = maxW.widgetId
  LEFT JOIN widgets w ON n.widgetid = w.widgetid 
    AND n.for_date + 1 = w.for_date
  WHERE n.for_date + 1 <= maxW.max_for_date
)
SELECT * 
FROM nodes_cte 
ORDER BY for_date
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/fee9a/1).

And the returned results (format the date however you'd like):

```
WIDGETID   FOR_DATE                     SCORE
1337       May, 07 2012 00:00:00+0000   12
1337       May, 08 2012 00:00:00+0000   41
1337       May, 09 2012 00:00:00+0000   41
1337       May, 10 2012 00:00:00+0000   41
1337       May, 11 2012 00:00:00+0000   500
```

Please note, this assumes your For_Date field is a Date -- if it includes a Time -- then you may need to use Interval '1 day' in the query above instead.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The data:

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE widget
        ( widget_id INTEGER NOT NULL
        , for_date DATE NOT NULL
        , score INTEGER
         , PRIMARY KEY (widget_id,for_date)
        );
INSERT INTO widget(widget_id , for_date , score) VALUES
 (1312, '2012-05-07', 20)
, (1337, '2012-05-07', 12)
, (1337, '2012-05-08', 41)
, (1337, '2012-05-11', 500)
        ;
```

The query:

```
SELECT w.widget_id AS widget_id
        , cal::date AS for_date
        -- , w.for_date AS org_date
        , w.score AS score
FROM generate_series( '2012-05-07'::timestamp , '2012-05-11'::timestamp
                 , '1day'::interval) AS cal
        -- "half cartesian" Join;
        -- will be restricted by the NOT EXISTS() below
LEFT JOIN widget w ON w.for_date <= cal
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM widget nx
        WHERE nx.widget_id = w.widget_id
        AND nx.for_date <= cal
        AND nx.for_date > w.for_date
        )
ORDER BY cal, w.widget_id
        ;
```

The result:

```
 widget_id |  for_date  | score 
-----------+------------+-------
      1312 | 2012-05-07 |    20
      1337 | 2012-05-07 |    12
      1312 | 2012-05-08 |    20
      1337 | 2012-05-08 |    41
      1312 | 2012-05-09 |    20
      1337 | 2012-05-09 |    41
      1312 | 2012-05-10 |    20
      1337 | 2012-05-10 |    41
      1312 | 2012-05-11 |    20
      1337 | 2012-05-11 |   500
(10 rows)
```